# Update with distinct on violates unique key in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

```
update schema.current_status a
set status       = stat.overall_status,
    created_date = stat.created_date,
    parent_id    = stat.parent_id,
    id  = stat.id
from (select distinct on (id) id,  parent_id, overall_status, created_date
from schema.daily
where parent_id
          =
      'abc'
     ) stat;
```

This is the query I am using, when I run just the sub query, I can see it is returning unique records only, but when I try to update the table, it says it violates unique key. My unique key is on parent_id, id

Comment: But where is a condition which sets the relation between updated row and source row? Something like `WHERE stat.id = a.id`.

Answer (score 1):

As Akina hinted at, without a relational predicate between your subquery and the outer parent query, this is going to try to `UPDATE` all rows in your `schema.current_status` table to the same value from your `schema.daily` table, violating the **unique key constraint**. This would only work if there was only a single record in your `schema.current_status` table. What is the relationship between `schema.current_status` and `schema.daily`?...as that's what you're currently missing in a predicate clause (such as a `WHERE` clause).